# Dynamically Changing CSS Background Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I'm looking for is a way to make my HTML header tag change background images every few seconds. Any solutions are welcome, as long as it is not to complex.

I have this code right now as well as linking to JQuery:

`<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

```
$(function() {
    var header = $(‘.mainHeader’);
    var backgrounds = new Array(
        ‘url(img/rainbow.jpg)’,
        ‘url(img/chickens_on_grass.jpg)’
        ‘url(img/cattle_on_pasture.jpg)’
        ‘url(img/csa_bundle.jpg)’
    );
    var current = 0;

    function nextBackground() {
        header.css(‘background’,backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);
        setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
    }

    setTimeout(nextBackground, 10000);
    header.css(‘background’, backgrounds[0]);
});
```

My HTML header:

`<header class="mainHeader"></header>`

And CSS:

```
.mainHeader {
    background: no-repeat center bottom scroll; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    min-height: 150px;
    padding-top: 2%;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Right now I have now background image at all.

Comment: Your array is wrong... there's a few commas missing..

Comment: quote strings are wrong too. http://jsfiddle.net/4LFnK/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var header = $('body');

var backgrounds = new Array(
    'url(http://placekitten.com/100)'
  , 'url(http://placekitten.com/200)'
  , 'url(http://placekitten.com/300)'
  , 'url(http://placekitten.com/400)'
);

var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
}
setInterval(nextBackground, 1000);

header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<header></header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks guys I got it working now thanks for all your help. One more thing though. Can I get this: `var header = $('header');` to call a `class` instead of the element. I want to apply to my HTML5 `<header class="mainheader">`?

Comment: Figured out the `class` thing everything seems to be working great thanks again for all your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: @CWDesign can you please change the accepted answer since this guy seems to have copied/pasted the anwswer from the user below?

Comment: How do I allow for a smooth transition when the background changes?

Comment: @RommelParas I would create and set the background-image to a direct child of body with z-index: -1 and play with opacity while changing the background image of the new container.

Comment: If you want this to be fluid even after switching tabs in your browser, don't use setInterval(). Instead use setTimeout() and restart the timeout (with setTimeout()) in that function. The reason for this is, that modern browsers pause inactive tabs and on reactivating them process all 'missed' events, in this case all intervals that had to be processed.

Answer (score 21):

Made a few amendments to your code

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/p77KW/**

```
var header = $('body');

var backgrounds = new Array(
    'url(http://placekitten.com/100)'
  , 'url(http://placekitten.com/200)'
  , 'url(http://placekitten.com/300)'
  , 'url(http://placekitten.com/400)'
);

var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
}
setInterval(nextBackground, 1000);

header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
```

Biggest changes (as noted in others comments) is that you have to use apostrophe**'**s, not those funky open and close single-quotes and that your array wasn't correct.

With these corrections out of the way I simplified a few things:

1. Increment `current` *then* take modulus (I know this is basically what you did but how much easier is that to debug `;)`)
2. Target `background-image` directly
3. Used `setInterval()` instead of a double call to `setTimeout`

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, but nothing is working yet. I copied and pasted your code into my page inside my `script` tags. Also tageted `background-image` like you said. Still I get no image at all, it makes no sense.

Comment: @CWDesign can you try it with the PlaceKitten links?

Comment: Yes I did, just like you had it.

Comment: @CWDesign any errors in the console? Can you give us a link?

Comment: It appears to work. You have to wait a while but it does work. The delay is caused by waiting for the images to load. Once loaded the code seems to run just fine; agreed?

Comment: Oof, those images are 1.5MB+ each!

Comment: Yes I got to find a way to keep the quality up but have a smaller image. next progect.

Comment: @CWDesign can I confirm with you that if you open the page, wait a couple of minutes, the functionality is correct?

Comment: It seems to flash some when it is changing images now that I just uploaded some smaller images.

Comment: @CWDesign You may wish to consider preloading your images (either as hidden elements on the page or via JS).

Answer (score 5):

You could acheive this same technique with HTML/CSS Only by 1. placing images within an "img" tag in your HTML surrounded by a "div wrapper" and setting it to position:relative and div wrapper img's to position:absolute. For full-width/full-height you can use percentages or potentially "background-size:cover" (haven't checked) and then call a CSS animation to change the images dynamically.

Or 2. you can add multiple images to a background in your CSS separated by commas, apply background-size:cover and again use CSS animations to change the background.

Here's an [example](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/) and also Mozilla [CSS3 Animation Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations)

Comment: This is a real solution here, HTML/CSS only solution is always preferable to added JavaScript! Thank you.

Comment: Can you expand on #2, what . css is there to actually rotate/change the stacked background images?

Answer (score 1):

You can't delimit JavaScript strings with `‘` characters. You must use `"` or `'`.

Comment: @daekano I hope you're joking.

Comment: @rvighne Of course I am :P
It's rare that you see those kinds of quotes anywhere outside of Word, in my experience.

Answer (score -1):

It must be late but may help to another one.
For this goal in some situations I prefer to use a jquery plugin named tcycle which have only a few lines of code and supports just fade transition, but it works smoothly even with large images.

Setting up a slideshow with tcycle is easy and even could be done with declarative markup such as

```
<div class="tcycle">
<img src="p1.jpg">
<img src="p2.jpg">
</div>
```

The trick could be donde using css z-index:-1 for container div and setting width and height to 100%

Homepage for downloading and check for other examples is [Malsup jQuery plugins](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/tcycle/)

Comment: This is a terrible idea.  It would load all the images first.