# Multi-background home page

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to set different background pictures for daily on homepage?  Like today would be first image, tomorrow would be second image, next tomorrow third image automatically. I have been researching on goggles but couldn't find on multi-backgrounds loops or cycle for CSS.

```
.bgImage {
background: url('../img/HighCityA.jpg') 20% 20% / cover transparent;    --Today
/*  background: url('../img/HighCityB.jpg') 20% 20% / cover transparent;*/ --Tomorrow
/*  background: url('../img/HighCityC.jpg') 20% 20% / cover transparent;*/  --Tuesday
/*  background: url('../img/HighCityD.jpg') 20% 20% / cover transparent;*/  --Wed
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top: -87px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 19%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1
}
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: You'll need JavaScript to do this.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py is correct! try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21760208/dynamicly-changing-css-background-image

Comment: Oh okay, I will check that one, thank you both of you.

Comment: @chipCholcate.py, do you have example of JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to loop through the stylesheet rules, find the rule for `.bgImage` and change its `background` properties according to the day.

`.getDay()` returns a number from `0`(`Sunday`) to `6`(`Saturday`).

```
var day = new Date().getDay();
var ss = document.styleSheets;

for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
  var rules = ss[i];
  for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
    var r = rules.cssRules[j];
    if (r.selectorText == ".bgImage") {
      r.style.backgroundPosition = '20% 20%';
      r.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
      r.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      // Sunday
      if (day == 0) {
        r.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/HighCityA.jpg)';
      }
      // Monday
      else if (day == 1) {
        r.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/HighCityB.jpg)';
      }
      // Tuesday
      else if (day == 2) {
        r.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/HighCityC.jpg)';
      }
      // Wednesday
      else if (day == 3) {
        r.style.backgroundImage = 'url(../img/HighCityD.jpg)';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could simplify this code to:

```
var day = new Date().getDay();
var ss = document.styleSheets;

for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
  var rules = ss[i];
  for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
    var r = rules.cssRules[j];
    if (r.selectorText == ".bgImage") {
      r.style.backgroundPosition = '20% 20%';
      r.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
      r.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      r.style.backgroundImage = day == 0 ? 'url(../img/HighCityA.jpg)' : day == 1 ? 'url(../img/HighCityB.jpg)' : day == 2 ? 'url(../img/HighCityC.jpg)' : day == 3 ? 'url(../img/HighCityD.jpg)' : ''
    }
  }
}
```

### Working Example

For a quick demonstration, I've used `backgroundColor` instead of `backgroundImage`.

```js
var day = new Date().getDay();
var ss = document.styleSheets;

for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
  var rules = ss[i];
  for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
    var r = rules.cssRules[j];
    if (r.selectorText == ".bgImage") {
      r.style.backgroundPosition = '20% 20%';
      r.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
      //.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      r.style.backgroundColor = day == 0 ? 'black' : day == 1 ? 'red' : day == 2 ? 'blue' : day == 3 ? 'green' : ''
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.bgImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top: -87px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 19%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="bgImage"></div>
```

Comment: Beautitful, that means " day == 1 ? 'red' " which is today, tomorrow would be blue.  I would add more days up to 6 with various backgroundColor or backgroundImage, correct?

Comment: @Carter - Yes, Exactly!

Comment: Awesome, it does help me alot.  I will focus on this part and many examples here.  I am overwhelmed a bit, lol.

Comment: Quick question - I added Javascript script tags in HTML file but doesn't response anything.  Please see [codePen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwgPOw). Not sure what little missing.

Comment: Does same thing as your CodePen suggestion, not working for me. :(

Comment: @Carter - Works fine for me.

Comment: Yeah I know, it works well.  I still don't get it why not working in sublime editor after I put scripts under head tags.

Comment: @Carter - You can't put JavaScript code under `head` tags.

Comment: @Carter - [Here is what it should look like](http://plnkr.co/edit/lWY8fI4PMmgH88m6nYkJ?p=preview).

Comment: Please see [Screenshot](http://oi62.tinypic.com/11lltfo.jpg), maybe something has to do with URL directions?  Yep, JavaScript code is now under body tags, background suppose to show "imageA.jpg".

Comment: @Carter - Change your urls to `url(img/name-of-the-image)` and it will work. In short, remove the `../` from `url(../img/name-of-the-image)`.

Comment: Yah!!  Now it is solved. Thank you man.  Style tags have to put always under head tags on the top before links/meta tags, can I transfer them to CSS file separately?

Comment: @Carter - Yes you can.

Comment: Okay, I add stylesheet link, how come it doesn't response anything to perceive style tags from the CSS file?         <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

Comment: @Carter - In your CSS file make sure you don't have `<style>` tags around the CSS rules that you've added.

Comment: Yep, I did. I will figure out why.  Have a great day! :)

Comment: Done - fixed everything.  Thank you!

Comment: @Carter - You're Welcome! Glad that you figured it out. :)

Comment: You are the best! :)  Just one note left - Console's error message says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null in line 60" -->  [Example -   for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) { ]

Comment: @Carter - Do you have an external CSS file? or you are just adding the styles in `style` tag directly in you html file?

Comment: in CSS file, not html file.

Comment: @Carter - Does the background change through JavaScript?

Comment: @Carter - It means, you have a css file that is empty, or it could be possible that your path is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using Javascript. You could for instance get the current day with the following JavaScript-Code:

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
```

Depending on the day of month you could then set the background image accordingly. For instance you could do:

```
var str1 = "url('http://www.yoururl.com/pathToImages/backgroundN.jpeg')";
document.getElementById("IdOfDivYouWantToStyle").style.backgroundImage = str1 ;
```

You could then set "backgroundN.jpeg" dynamically according to the day of month. You could even let the source code unchanged and simply change the pictures in your folder.

Comment: After reading your example, just wonder what should I put instead ""IdOfDivYouWantToStyle"?

Comment: Just give it the Id of the HTML element whose background you want to change e.g. a <div> tag or your body tag or whatever you want to set the style on.

Answer (score 1):

You can try jquery/javascript like this;

```
var date = new Date();
var weekdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

var weekday = weekdays[date.getDay()];
if(weekday=='Monday'){
$('.bgImg').css('background-image', 'url(' + monday_imageUrl + ')');
}else if(weekday=='Tuesday'){
$('.bgImg').css('background-image', 'url(' + tuesday_imageUrl + ')');
}
```

...

Comment: Thank you Debasish for another example!

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {          
  var i =0;
  var images = ['image2.png','image3.png','image1.png'];
  var image = $('#slideit');
                //Initial Background image setup
  image.css('background-image', 'url(image1.png)');
                //Change image at regular intervals
  setInterval(function(){  
   image.fadeOut(1000, function () {
   image.css('background-image', 'url(' + images [i++] +')');
   image.fadeIn(1000);
   });
   if(i == images.length)
    i = 0;
  }, 5000);           
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
      <div id="slideit" style="width:700px;height:391px;"> 
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this. I am sure this will work. this eg is for changing image after every 5 seconds. try setting it as you want !

Comment: Thank you Avnish!  I found it very similar from google via codePen but I really like it.  I prefer different days instead every 5 seconds which is less annoying.

Comment: Oh welcome @Carter ! you can use it with  31536000 seconds, if you wish too.Also chipChocolate.py answer is good !

Answer (score 0):

```js
var day = new Date().getDay();
var ss = document.styleSheets;

for (i = 0; i < ss.length; i++) {
  var rules = ss[i];
  for (j = 0; j < rules.cssRules.length; j++) {
    var r = rules.cssRules[j];
    if (r.selectorText == ".bgImage") {
      r.style.backgroundPosition = '20% 20%';
      r.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
      //.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
      r.style.backgroundColor = day == 0 ? 'black' : day == 1 ? 'red' : day == 2 ? 'blue' : day == 3 ? 'green' : ''
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.bgImage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top: -87px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 19%;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div class="bgImage"></div>
```