# Refreshing page with a new image

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I currently have a stagnant image on my site:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="/stylesheets/normalize.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="/stylesheets/master.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
window.onload = function () {

    var images = [],
        i=1, indexImages = true,
        prefix = '../image/',
        extension = '.jpg';

    while (indexImages) {
        var a = new XMLHttpRequest(); a.open('GET', prefix+i+extension, false); a.send();

        if (a.status != 404) { i += 1; images.push(prefix+i+extension); } else {
            indexImages = false;

            localStorage['backgroundIndex'] = !localStorage['backgroundIndex']?0:+localStorage['backgroundIndex']+2>images.length?0:+localStorage['backgroundIndex']+1;
            document.body.style.backgroundImage =  'url(' + images[+localStorage['backgroundIndex']] + ')';

        }
    }

}
</script>

<style>
body {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-color: black;

    border-bottom: 8px solid  #7D8A28;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
  <section id="card">
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

It's just that I want it to be a different image each time the page refreshes, so it auto changes to 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 10.jpg, whatever. (There are hundreds to choose from)

Could someone help me out with a solution? I'm not very good at this, and this is my first site.

Thanks.

Comment: [Dynamically Changing CSS Background Image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21760208/1761793)

Comment: Yeah, but that says this: ‘url(img/rainbow.jpg)’,
        ‘url(img/chickens_on_grass.jpg)’
        ‘url(img/cattle_on_pasture.jpg)’
        ‘url(img/csa_bundle.jpg)’ - I have literally hundreds.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think CSS alone can do this, here's an answer:

## Random

```
window.onload = function () {
    var images = [
        'image/1.png',
        'image/2.png',
        'image/3.png',
        'image/4.png'
    ];

    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[Math.floor(Math.random()*images.length)] + ')';
}
```

This will load a random image every time you visit the page.

---

## Specified Order

To load them in sequential order: First time image1, second time image2. **The images don't need even have a number for this to work just fine**. Do:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var images = [
        'image/A.png',
        'image/B.png',
        'image/C.png',
        'image/D.png'
    ];

    localStorage['backgroundIndex'] = !localStorage['backgroundIndex']?0:+localStorage['backgroundIndex']+2>images.length?0:+localStorage['backgroundIndex']+1;

    document.body.style.backgroundImage =  'url(' + images[+localStorage['backgroundIndex']] + ')';
}
```

---

#### Generating the Array (ONLY IF YOUR IMAGES HAVE A NUMBER AT THE END)

This will automatically generate the array for you **and you don't have to provide the amount of images**

```
window.onload = function () {

    var images = [],
        i = 1,
        prefix = 'image/',
        extension = '.png',
        max = 1000;

    function index() {
        var a = new XMLHttpRequest();
        a.open('GET', prefix + i + extension, false);
        a.send();
        a.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (a.readyState === 4) {
                if (a.status != 404) {
                    i += 1;
                    images.push(prefix + i + extension);
                    i < max ? index();
                } else {}

                localStorage['backgroundIndex'] = !localStorage['backgroundIndex'] ? 0 : +localStorage['backgroundIndex'] + 2 > images.length ? 0 : +localStorage['backgroundIndex'] + 1;
                document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + images[+localStorage['backgroundIndex']] + ')';

            }

        };
    }

    index();
}
```

---

#### Most versatile solution

If you have PHP, this is probably the best solution in terms of working in many cases. *But you really don't want to use PHP if you can avoid it*. **It will get all images in a directory to generate the array**:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var images = (JSON.parse("<?=scandir('../images')?>")||[]).filter(function (a) {  return ['.', '..'].indexOf(a) < 0;  });

    document.body.style.backgroundImage =  'url(' + images[+localStorage['backgroundIndex']] + ')';

};
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `backgroundImage`'s URL to the image must be encapsulated within an `'url()'` statement, otherwise it wouldn't work. As in... `document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(pix.jpg);'`

Comment: @AlfonsoGarnett Yes, I forgot that. Fixed

Comment: `<?=scandir('/images')?>` will cause "Notice: Array to string conversion"

Comment: Not relaly working for me. Could you tel me what I'm doing wrong?   http://codepad.org/gUVeDFbS#output

Comment: So far, your ajax does not randomize the image and it will always display `1.jpg`. The loop starts at 1 and never goes further. The AJAX will always get stuck in an infinite loop. To at least fix the infinite loop, move your declaration of `indexImages` outside of the `window.onload`

Comment: @HandyDan Where'd you get that from?

Comment: Your 3rd answer. The one that Brian was referring to. Your only solution that has a loop.

Comment: @HandyDan Depends on if it fails. I updated to a more fail-safe version.

Comment: @vihan1086 Are you testing your scripts? Your third solution still does not work. It only tries to loads `1.png` and no matter if it fails or succeeds, it does not move on to the next image. Yes I downvoted your answer, purely because your last two solutions currently do not work. But there is no need to be vindictive and downvote my answer with two solutions that not only work, but work cross browser. Please test your solutions

Comment: @HandyDan I don't care if you down voted my answer, go ahead and down vote all my answers. You're suggesting using PHP and wasting server side resources for *changing the background*. I've added multiple answers in case one of them doesn't work for OP. You're also suggesting PHP is better because it will automatically index the folder. That can be done with JavaScript also. No need for AJAX because you would need to add it to an array is what you're saying. That's not correct and you're misinforming the OP. *That's the exact reason we're using AJAX* is so OP doesn't have to do that.

Comment: @vihan1086 Third answer edited, now works as you intended. You are trying to build a list of the files by making an iterative AJAX request loop. Unfortunately, it is really inefficient since it keeps making requests to the server for each image until it 404s (downloading each image entirely). It's highly unreasonable since OP said in a comment that he has hundreds of images. And all the files would need to be named numerically... My solution will efficiently choose a random image from a directory without the meticulous maintenance of a ascending numeric naming convention, with only one request

Comment: @vihan1086 Please suport your claim that I am misinforming the OP, in other words: Please provide documentation of a client side scripting language this is able to efficiently list the contents of a server side directory without the assistance of a server side language (PHP, Node.js, etc)

Comment: @HandyDan It doesn't seem like OP has PHP installed in his computer. I also have a PHP solution which OP can use. It looks like OP *already has the images numbered numerically*.  You said *"there is no added benefit to using AJAX. Any time you add an image, you would have to add it to your JS array. The only reason we're using AJAX is to avoid this. I'm not going to get so hung up about one answer. You can go cry about this all you want but I'm just going to stop replying. Both of our answers are inefficient OP should use CRON jobs to index the directory & generate a JSON with all the images

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do it with JavaScript. You could define an array with all the images you have and then create a random number every time the page loads. Then use the random number to access the array's index to read the name of the image. Like so:

```js
var images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg", "image3.jpg", "image4.jpg", "image5.jpg"];

var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * images.length));
//images[randomNumber] contains your random image
```

Hope it helps.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I see all these JS solutions but most likely you need a php one as I am sure you don't wanna put the names of hundreds of images in a file. So if you have some knowledge of programming in php then try this.

1. Generate a random number. Let's say it is 42
2. Read the file names one by one (http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)
3. Once you reach the 42nd file, pass it to the page.

You can either put the filename directly in the css or have a php page as a background image source which returns the images. Either case, the above steps will give you what you want.

---

The above works well if file names and types are different. However, if file names are numerical and all files are the same extension then just generating a number and just using it as the file name is slightly faster than the above method.

However, it is still faster than most JS solution. Remember that JS is on client side. That mean it will be executed after that page is loaded. With JS, files need to be as minimal as possible. Otherwise, the page would load and you wouldn't have a background until that request is returned. Considering all these delays, I wouldn't call JS efficient over PHP.

Although you can always make it nice and fade it in or something :)

Comment: I'm sorry but your solution is just bad. Why wouldn't you just grab a random image at execution instead of making requests to the server?

Comment: var a = new XMLHttpRequest(); a.open('GET', prefix+i+extension, false); a.send();

Comment: If you are using PHP you wouldn't want to read file names one by one, that's pretty dang inefficient and when doing server-side code, you want to be as efficient as possible

Comment: not really since the code and the files are on the same machine

Comment: Anyway, nice idea :) just a bit inefficient *in my opinion*

Answer (score -1):

## No need for AJAX

### Why you should use PHP

The added benefit of using PHP is we can make it so all you have to do is drop an image into a folder and it will automatically be added to the randomized list! Which is great for maintainability. You code it once, and leave it alone!

In my opinion, there is no added benefit to using AJAX. Any time you add an image, you would have to add it to your JS image array. However, I don't know your exact scenario.

### Important

All the other solutions that mention PHP, so far, have failed to mention one very important part... the page you are working in must be parsed as a PHP file.
There are two ways to do so:

1. Parse html/htm page as php page via .htaccess (**advanced**)
2. Change your the page extension to '.php' (**simple**)

(My solution requires that your page is parsed as PHP)

---

## Solution 1

I would use JavaScript to randomly select the image from a PHP generated list, then append CSS to apply the background image to the page before the `window.onload` event.

### PHP with JavaScript Random

Append the following to page head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php
    // Path to image can be a relative or absolute path. I recommend absolute.
    // The following is my absolute path.
    $img_dir_path = '/rand-img/images/';

    // Get directory list. If using absolute, prepend $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for php
    $dir_listing  = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$img_dir_path, 1);

    // array_diff() to remove '.' & '..' from front of $dir_listing array
    $img_array    = array_diff( $dir_listing, array('.', '..') );
    ?>

    // JavaScript variables
    var img_dir_path = '<?php echo $img_dir_path ?>';
    var img_array    = <?php echo json_encode($img_array) ?>;
    var rand_index   = Math.floor(Math.random() * img_array.length);
    var img_path     = img_dir_path + img_array[rand_index];

    // no need to wait for window.onload if we append actual style tag
    var css   = 'body { background-image: url('+img_path+') !important; }',
        head  = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
        style = document.createElement('style');

    style.type = 'text/css';

    if (style.styleSheet){
        style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
    } else {
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
    }

    head.appendChild(style);
</script>
```

Using PHP for random, will only work if the page is loaded without cache.
However, using JavaScript will randomize the image even if the actual page is cached.

---

## Solution 2

In my experience, this solution will randomize the image the vast majority of the time. However, if the page is loaded via cache, the background image will not be re-randomized.

### PHP Random

Append the following to page head:

```
<?php
// Path to image can be a relative or absolute path. I recommend absolute.
// The following is my absolute path.
$img_dir_path = '/rand-img/images/';

// Get directory list. If using absolute, prepend $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for php
$dir_listing  = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$img_dir_path, 1);

// array_diff() to remove '.' & '..' from front of $dir_listing array
$img_array    = array_diff( $dir_listing, array('.', '..') );

// Random number based off size of $img_array
$random_index = mt_rand(0, count($img_array)-1);

// Build image path
$image_path   = $img_dir_path . $dir_listing[ $random_index ];

?>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-image: url("<?php echo $image_path ?>");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-color: black;

        border-bottom: 8px solid  #7D8A28;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: PHP for changing the background image? Now you solution is getting a bit too crazy for such a simple task

Comment: Not really, its much more accessible to all users. The user would not require JavaScript to view the image.

Comment: also, the only reason I'm using AJAX is to *not* have to update the array every time. It will get all images in a directory

Comment: @vihan1086 Sorry, but I don't see making AJAX requests to the server for an unknown amount of images as a good practice solution.