# Override CSS class

Tags: javascript, css

I have a CSS class in my code that overrides a class of one specific library. Using this I'm able to override `.libraryclass.libraryclass-something` with one specific image

```
#myobject .libraryclass.libraryclass-something {
    background: url("../../../images/Image1") no-repeat 0 0;    
}
```

Now I have to use a condition in my JS but in case to use Image1 I need to use Image2. I can create another class similar to the first one pointed to Image2 but I don't know how to do it because I always need to override the class `.libraryclass.libraryclass-something`.

Let's say in my JS file.

```
If (a===1) {
    #myobject .libraryclass.libraryclass-something
}
else {
    ??? (because I need to respect the same name...)
}
```

Comment: You could create 2 new classes and add them to the element(s) you want to have your images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can create something like this.](https://jsfiddle.net/1ru5wm67/1/)

```
#myobject .libraryclass.libraryclass-something.two {
    background: url("../../../images/Image2") no-repeat 0 0;    
}
```

This will still override `.libraryclass.libraryclass-something`, but you can add a `.two` to make it display `Image2` instead.

Answer (score 0):

2 steps to do this:

1. Create a new class with just the differences/additions of the existing class. In your case, you want to change the background so create a new class with the new background.
2. Write script as you are doing now and add this new class to your element. Snippet from your question:

   ```
   else {
   $('#myobject .libraryclass.libraryclass-something').addClass('newclass');
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could use the [switchClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/) method

e.g. (from jquery docs)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>switchClass demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <style>
  div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
  }
  .big {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .blue {
    background-color: #00f;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="big"></div>

<script>
$( "div" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).switchClass( "big", "blue", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: or look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21771135/1675954 might need tweaking